# Remove draggable object jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have draggable objects, how can I add remove button to delete this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming some HTML structure as follows..

```
<div class="draggable-container">

    <div class="close">
    </div>

</div>

.draggable-container
{
    position:relative;
}

.close
{

    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    cursor:pointer;

}

$('.draggable-container .close').click(function(){
   //implement close here
   // eg: $(this).closest('.draggable-container').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an example:

```
$(<your draggable objects selector>).append('<div class="close">close</div>');
$('.close', <your draggable objects selector>).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```