# Add 'Remove/Delete' option to draggable object

Tags: jquery, object, draggable

I have a draggable object i would like to provide the option to close/remove.
I have been able to add the "close" text to the object, however when i click on the "close" text the object is not removed.

I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452538/remove-draggble-object-jquery-ui)
Below is my code

```
//Add the close property to the dragged object
$(clonedObject).append('<div class="close">close</div>');

//Add click event to delete object
$('.close', clonedObject).click(function () {
    $(clonedObject).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. The issue was that the target div tag was nested. Once i removed the inner div tag, the click event worked.

```
                <div id="textbox" class="draggableItem">                
                <span class="draghandle">::</span>
                <div class="item">
                <span class="draggableItemContentText">Text Box</span>
                </div>
                </div>
```

The solution should be displayed as shown below,

```
        <div id="textbox" class="draggableItem">                
            <span class="draghandle">::</span>
            <span class="draggableItemContentText">Text Box</span>
        </div>
```